# Plugin to reformat the post automatically after submitting

Tags: plugins

I am looking for a plugin that can:

- Remove links and images from the post
- Remove any other strings/text that I specify
- Republish and done

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `transition_post_status` to filter the content after submitting the post.

Try the below code in the `functions.php` in your theme:

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', '_new_post', 10, 3 );

function _new_post( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( 'publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( 'post' !== $post->post_type ) {
        return;
    } // restrict the filter to a specific post type

    $plain_content = strip_tags( $post->post_content );
    $new_post      = array(
        'ID'           => $post->ID,
        'post_content' => $plain_content,
    );

    wp_update_post( $new_post );
}
```

Comment: This seems like a genius solution. But how do I use it? I mean where do I put this code?

Comment: Updated! you should put in the `functions.php`

Comment: OK. And how do I define the data that I want to strip/remove from the created post?

Comment: You can add your data in the `$new_post` variable. in the above code, the HTML code striped in the content. You can do some change in the contents when the post will be published.

Comment: For example let say i want to keep the "RSI is 74" text and remove the rest of the text from this post http://prntscr.com/gye5hv

Comment: Use `'post_content' => 'RSI is ' . $post->ID,`

Comment: But each time RSI number is different lets say right now its "RSI is 74" in another post it will be "RSI is 84" or something else. Would the above code work?

Comment: In the above code, RSI number can't different because I get from `$post->ID`.

Comment: OK. So any other possible  solution? Perhaps something like find a replace from line numbers?

Comment: It's possible just you should use a condition in the code for checking number. Perhaps this answer is your question and doesn't forget to select the answer to useful.